# Method for managing callbacks for RPC

Tags: javascript, rpc

I am building (yet another) RPC client/server for calling methods between a browser and a Node.js server.  (My reason for this is that I already have streams and serialization taken care of by [BinaryJS](http://binaryjs.com/), and there is no solid solution that I've already seen that simply uses object streams for RPC.  [rpc-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/rpc-stream) seemed like a good fit, but it only allowed for a single callback and was inflexible in parameter ordering and what not.)

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement callbacks.  Suppose on the client, I call some code like this:

```
rpcClient.someRemoteMethod('parameter1', 'parameter2', function callback1 () {
  // callback1
}, function callback2 () {
  // callback2
});
```

I would expect the client to then create a message to the RPC server along these lines:

```
{
    method: 'someRemoteMethod',
    parameters: ['parameter1', 'parameter2', /* something to reference callback1 */, /* something to reference callback2 */]
}
```

On the server end, the RPC server could do something like:

```
wrappedObject[data.method].apply(parameters);
```

How do I handle the callbacks though?  Obviously I need to create some function on the fly that then sends a set of parameters back to the other end, as well as shuffles the return value back to the server.  This isn't too hard... I can have a set of IDs or something to track functions in a collection.  However, how long do I keep one of these dynamically created callbacks around on the server end?

If I create one of these callback functions, how do I know that all references to it have been removed, other than the reference in my collection of callbacks?  I don't want to get into a situation where I have millions of callbacks in a collection sitting around just because other code *might* call them some time.

For what it's worth, [Socket.IO had a similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/nTr5AJWA2c0) a couple years ago.  I don't know if it still applies.

Comment: Maybe represent the callbacks as <methodname>[<callbackIndex>] `someRemoteMethod[0]` and include the number of callbacks as another parameter in the message body? I would clean up the reference immediately after the callback otherwise you will be implementing TCP trying to validate if the data successfully went back and forth.

Comment: After reading your question again, I'm a little confused about where the callbacks live.  On the client or on the server?  If it's on the server, why does the client have to know about the callback?

Comment: Suppose I have a callback that can be called multiple times.  Or, a callback that never gets called.  In most cases, the client will have the callback function and the server will simply be calling it... but it doesn't matter as the return value could have another function.  Basically, if a function is to be serialized, the serializing end will need to keep a reference to that function indefinitely, to be called when the remote end calls it, since there is no "remote garbage collection", and as far as I know, no way to count references.

Comment: I did just find this NPM package:  https://github.com/AlexeyKupershtokh/node-candle  It seems to be built for what I'm doing, but I'm wondering if there might be a different creative solution out there.  Otherwise, I have to guess a time limit at when I would want that callback destroyed.

Comment: I wouldn't track the clients callbacks on the server.  Just assume each time the client makes a call that it will create new callbacks each time (even if they are the same ones) and allow the client to decide how long they live for.

Comment: After checking it out some more, I think I know what you mean.  I don't have much experience in the domain, so I could only offer looking into WeakMaps which is what that library you linked to uses.